# Uploading a file to Sharepoint on iPad modifies filename

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, apple-ios

I am using an iPad to upload files to a SharePoint library from OneDrive.

The SharePoint Online library is using modern experience.

The added file names are changed after upload. A GUID is prepended to the file name.

eg. file uploaded with name:  `testc3.docx`.

Filename modified to `817BFD26-C1E2-4384-9663-1D9C59EC9C4Etestc3.docx`

Anybody any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?

Everything works fine on PC.

[image: view after uploading files on ipad]

On classic mode (2013) the **upload** button is disabled so cannot upload a file at the library level.

On classic mode (2010) the **Add Document** allows you to add a file but same result.
ie filename gets modified.

Tried on OOB multiple libraries - same result

also chose to add file from IOS photos library - same result so not restricted to onedrive.

Fired up the Sharepoint App.

On side menu clicked Files and navigated to folder. (assume this is accessing by the app)
Clicked + on top right - only option is Create New Folder.
Can't see any option to upload a file

Returned to home menu and clicked on home on sidenav.
This accesses via the browser and allows me to upload a file but with the prepended guid on the filename.

Has anybody uploaded a file to a Sharepoint library other than from another Sharepoint library on an iPad and if so please outline steps taken

Comment: Check whether the issue exists in other libraries when upload files from ipad.        
Check whether the issue exists in classic experience when upload files from ipad.

Comment: I cant add comments, but are you uploading using the app? or a browser?

Comment: are you uploading using the app? or a browser? - @Ravi Kothari

Answer (score 1):

I posted this issue on the Microsoft Community site
[Post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdaccessories-mdaccessories_other/uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-on-ipad-modifies/846a918a-4981-4198-80ef-0d795c2bf063?tm=1559707894260)

I did not change anything but now am unable to reproduce the issue and everything works as expected ie filename is no longer been modified